# Loading Dialog box in android

Tags: android

I am developing one application in Android. My application has one service. My service is always running in background. My background service keep monitoring of region define by user.

Now when user go out range my application give alert to user. Now my problem is below :

1. When my application is closed i.e. not running, then my application
   get alert.
2. When my application is running then sometimes it get alert and some
   times not.

Below is the code i.e. activity that will load alert for when user go out of range.

```
//SecuRemote.LOG("current activity context" + SecuRemote.currentActivityContext);
Intent i = new Intent(context, ShowAlertDialog.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
i.putExtra("Msg",msg);
if(status){
    i.putExtra("status","true");
    if(devName != null)
        i.putExtra("devName",devName);
} else
    i.putExtra("status","false");
    SecuRemote.LOG("start activity showAlertDialog" + context);
    context.startActivity(i);
```

Looking some good response...
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in the programming logic -

1. Your `service` should probably be checking for a flag that says `isInside` or not,so by the time user enters your application this flag will be toggled saying `isInside=true` and `onPause or on onDestroy` whatever you think is gonna serve your purpose you should toggle the flag

//Service part and dialog showing

so in your `service` as it will be checking for the flag,as soon as it checks `isInside=false` it raises an alert using the code mentioned above....I would recommend you to show that above activity(the alert activity) as an dialog by putting the theme attribute of that activity as dialog ....

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

i hope it helps you.